# How can I create new key in a registry and set its value in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, key, registry

I've been trying to do it for over a week but I still don't know how to do it. I want to create new key in LOCAL_MACHINE in registry. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCSTR sk = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
    LONG openRes = RegCreateKeyExA(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        sk,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        REG_OPTION_CREATE_LINK,
        WRITE_OWNER,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        NULL);
    if (openRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Success creating key" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Error creating key" << endl;
    }

    LPCSTR val = "example_value";
    LPCSTR data = "example_data";

    LONG setRes = RegSetValueExA(hKey, val, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, (strlen(data) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Success writing to Registry" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Error writing to Registry" << endl;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I also run the app as an administrator so I thought it shouldn't be a problem to create a key, but it actually is. Kind of result is "Success creating key" and "Success writing to Registry", but when I look into the registry, I don't see any changes. Has anybody got an idea what's going on?

Comment: Why you call RegSetValueExA with sizeof(WCHAR) ? Also are you sure that is you not victim of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization ?

Comment: you're right, i was changing the code several times and i forgot about it but now i changed the WCHAR into char and also nothing happened so it isn't the problem, but i'll change it also here

Comment: Registry redirection.....

Comment: but how can i fix it?